# On click drop-down

Tags: drop-down-menu, click

I am curious, how to change the code that drop-down opens and closes only by clicking on the link. Because now it also closes and opens if you click on the body of the drop-down itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "ul" ).click(function() {
    $(this).children('li:not(.init)').slideToggle(0);
    $(this).find("li.init").toggleClass("init1");
  });

});
```

```css
.selectContainer ul{
 width:200px;
}

.selectContainer ul li
  {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
 list-style: none;
  }
  
.selectContainer ul li:not(.init){
    display:none;
    float:left;
  }
 li.init{position:relative;}
 li.init:after{content:"\2193 ";position:absolute;right:5px;}
 li.init1:after{content:"\2191 ";position:absolute;right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="selectContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="init">Select</li>
                <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
                <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>                                                          
            </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
 $( "ul li.init" ).click(function(e) {  
     $('li:not(.init)').slideToggle(0);
     $(this).toggleClass("init1");   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You query the "ul"-element with `$( "ul" )` and define it's `click`. Obviously all the space after it is part of the ul-element.

Why don't you try to set the `$("li.init").click` instead. Inside the function you could query for the "ul" just as in your example. But set the `.click` of the "li".